# Chmod +x seems not working

Tags: 16.04, command-line, permissions

I'm new to Linux , so please just don't blast me.

I have downloaded a ".run" file on my Ubuntu 17 .

And i want to install it, so via shell i execute the

```
sudo chmod +x file.run
```

command to take the previlege of executing the file.

If then i execute the command

```
./file.run
```

an error appears and it tells me that i have to use the "sudo" prefix in order to execute this last command.

But , why ? I have used chmod just to execute the file without the sudo prefix .-.

Answer (score 7):

`chmod +x file.run` gives the file the *execute* permission but it does not control whose permissions the file has when it executes.

`./file.run` runs the file with the privileges of your user.

`sudo ./file.run` runs the file with the privileges of root.

Your `file.run` apparently needs root privileges.  That is why `sudo ./file.run` is needed.

Comment: So there are 2 separate layers of permissions ?

Comment: @Tantaros It’s one layer but with a [lot of features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)). You need the execute permission on your script and it most likely needs the write permission on system files.